# Lua script for iOS getColors within range?

Tags: ios, iphone, lua, autotouch

I am trying to capture the pixel color of a specific letter in a font within an iOS app.  I'd then use that color in an if/then statement to determine the next action of my script.  I'm finding no easy way to determine if the color/colors I'm finding are the right ones.  Here's my current process:  I start recording my inputs and continuously click around the letter.  I end up with something like touchdown(123,456).  I change that to alert(getColor(123,456)) and run, which produces a popup that tells me the color such as 3094841 (not sure why the colors are in numeric format, but they are).  I do this for each touchdown line that is captured.  The problem is, I don't know an easy way to determine which color is the small letter I'm trying to tap.

Is there a lua function that will capture and display a range of colors between 2 points?  If there were, I could see the commonality of all of the colors within the 2 points and make at least an educated guess as to which is the color in the font.  Or even more useful - is there a tool I can use to type in the color I'm getting back and have it display the corresponding color, so I can compare them.  That'd be the easiest.  Hope this makes sense.  Any help would be awesome.  In case it matters, I'm using Autotouch 8 on an iPhone 5.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function often in my games.
I find the easiest way to get a color you want to execute every single time is to take a snap of the screen you're checking and then use the helper on     getColor(x, y)

And you can use this to alert your color.

```
local color = getColor(x, y)
alert(color)
-- You can also use:
log(color)--this one keeps it in your log in case you can write it down immediately.
```

To use this in an if/then statement

```
function = namedfunction()
    local color = getColor(x, y)
    if color == YOURCOLOR then

    else 

    end
end

namedfunction();
```

Note that I have the iPhone 5 iOS 8.3 and I have the most recent AutoTouch from Cydia. If you don't have the helper when you're scripting it might be worth it to check if Cydia offers a capatable version.

Edit: I am running version 3.5.3-8 of Autotouch.

Comment: I'm using the same version of autotouch.  I've taken a snap like you suggested, but I'm not seeing anything called a  "helper."  Does this show you colors within range of a selection to "help" you identify the right one?  Can you explain the helper and where to find it?  Or are you just referring to the help documentation for autotouch?

Comment: Nevermind - found it.  This will be a huge help.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Before this update it was extremely hard to use these functions when only scripting on the iPhone. But allowing you to pull up the screen shot and pinpoint a pixel makes it do-able now.